# How to avoid that decorators break inspection of parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created this decorator that helps me to catch and log exceptions:

```
def log_exceptions(f):
    '''Catch exception in method, format message and log it.'''
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except CommandError:
            raise
        except Exception as e:
            error_type = sys.exc_info()[0].__name__
            error_desc = str(e)
            error_file = os.path.basename(sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)
            error_line = sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next.tb_lineno
            logger.info('Exception at %s (line: %s), %s: %s',
                        error_file, error_line, error_type, error_desc)
            return
    return wrapper
```

Now, if I define the method foo:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self, arg1, arg2 = None):
        pass
```

And inspect it, I get it's list of arguments:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(a.foo)
FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'arg1', 'arg2'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(None,), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

But if I use the log_exceptions decorator:

```
class A(object):
    @log_exceptions
    def foo(self, arg1, arg2 = None):
        pass
```

The inspection of arguments ceases to work (it gets the decorator's arguments):

```
>>> a = A()
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(a.foo)
FullArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', varkw='kwargs', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

Does anyone knows a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution at PEP-0362: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362

To replace a wrapper's signature with the signature of the wrapped one:

```
from inspect import signature
def decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.__signature__ = signature(f)

    return wrapper
```