# Preserve argument information for inspect when stacking decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-injection, reflection, decorator

I'm writing a decorator that should pass a query to the function based on one of its parameters.

This is how it currently looks like, but not finished yet (still experimenting):

```py
def pass_query(service: str, query: str):
    def decorate(decoratee):
        @functools.wraps(decoratee)
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            params = inspect.getfullargspec(decoratee)
            if "query" in params and service == params.get("service", None):
                kwargs["query"] = query
            return decoratee(*args, **kwargs)

        return decorator

    return decorate
```

The problem is that `inspect.getfullargspec(decoratee)` doesn't retrieve any useful information with two or more decorators as then the other ones loose the information about the function parameters.

```py
@pass_query("foo", "q1.sql")
@pass_query("bar", "q2.sql")
def track_report(service: str, query: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
    pass
```

Is there a way to preserve the parameters so that the decorators won't break reflection as if there was only one decorator?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```py
import inspect
decorator.__signature__ = inspect.signature(decoratee)
```

**In Detail**
In Python 3.10 `functools.wraps` does only copy `__module__` `__name__` `__qualname__` `__doc__` and `__annotations__` and updates `__dict__`.
For more details on it see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55102697/22511039) or the python code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1f7d64608b5c7f4c3d96b01b33e18ebf9dec8490/Lib/functools.py#L32)

But it does not touch the functions signature.
If you want to update it as well you can use `inspect.signature(decoratee)` and assign it to `decorator.__signature__` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32342831/22511039). The code will then look like this:

```py
def pass_query(service: str, query: str):
    def decorate(decoratee):
        @functools.wraps(decoratee)
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            params = inspect.getfullargspec(decoratee)
            if "query" in params and service == params.get("service", None):
                kwargs["query"] = query
            return decoratee(*args, **kwargs)

        # added this line
        decorator.__signature__ = inspect.signature(decoratee)
        return decorator

    return decorate
```

**Original Answer**
As I have not the reputation to flag this as a duplicate, I write it as an answer (please correct me if this is wrong).

A similar question has already been asked here and its accepted answer was working for me:
[How to avoid that decorators break inspection of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342663/how-to-avoid-that-decorators-break-inspection-of-parameters)

Comment: This looks like THE solution. As soon as I am able to test it, I'll give you a the tick.